# Moving an ImageView within a ListView

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

I'm looking to make it so that `onClick` my `ImageView` moves from the left side of my `ListView` to the right side.

I've tried applying an animation to the ImageView directly into the adapter however this hasn't worked and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great, Thank you in advance.

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.example.customlistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] images;
    ImageView image;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, int[] i) {
        this.context = c; //sets the application context that has been passed to the adapter
        this.images = i; //sets the images array that has been passed to the adapter
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater.from(context)); //sets the layout inflater from context
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { //total number of elements in the array
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { //gets the item using the position
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { //gets the item position
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { //this is used to update the view

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null); //inflates layout with custom_layout

        image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView); //finds the imageview in the new layout
        image.setImageResource(images[position]); //sets image resource to image array and viewposition

        final int p = position; //finalises position to be used in onClick method
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_right); //loads in animation from folder
                image.startAnimation(animation);

            }
        });
        return convertView; //returns the
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.customlistview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView; //listview holder

    int[] images = {R.drawable.img01, //images array
    R.drawable.img02,
    R.drawable.img03,
    R.drawable.img04};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView); //find the listview in view

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images); //new customadapter with images array
        //passes information of images and application context to the item adapter
        mListView.setAdapter(customAdapter); //sets the listview values with customAdapter

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and probably spent way too much time overthinking it.

I simply made a new method inside the adapter that held the animation code and set up a `onClick` listener inside the `getView` method that runs the animation

I don't know exactly what was causing the problem or what solved it but it works so im happy.

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View convertView) {
                runAnimation(convertView); //Animates the ImageView
            }
        });
        return convertView;
```

```
public void runAnimation(View convertView) {
        ImageView img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img2); //get the imageView from the child
        //Animates the Image within the child
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration
        img.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
    }
```